# Matlabpool configuration

Tags: parallel-processing, cluster-computing, matlab

I have a problem. I need to set a machine with 32 cores in local setting(to matlabpool), but it says to me that the maximum number is 8 cores(I knew that). The configuration must be in a script because I'm using a cluster.

Comment: I know that with local configuration is impossible, but would i have any other option?

Answer (score 1):

In release R2011b, the limit has increased to 12, see the [release notes](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/distcomp/rn/bs15q67.html#bs58_ld-1). That still doesn't help you enough though - to exceed that limit you must purchase [MATLAB Distributed Computing Server](http://www.mathworks.com/products/distriben/) licences to run on your cluster.

Using the latest (R2012a) syntax, you can export and import cluster 'Profiles' (formerly known as 'Configurations') using [`parallel.exportProfile`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/distcomp/parallel.exportprofile.html) and [`parallel.importProfile`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/distcomp/parallel.importprofile.html).